# Error while accessing SAP data using Azure data factory CDC connector

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are trying to read data from SAP using Azure data factory change data capture(CDC) connector. We get the below error when tried to access the data. The connector works fine for full load and it fails for delta load.

*Error Message: DF-SAPODP-012 - SapOdp copy activity failure with run id: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-4444-826e-XXXXX, error code: 2200 and error message: ErrorCode=SapOdpOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Sap Odp operation 'OpenOdpRead' failed. Error Number: '013', error message: 'Error while accessing',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SapRfcHelper,', Exception: com.microsoft.dataflow.Utils$.failure(Utils.scala:76)
com.microsoft.dataflow.store.sapodp.SapOdpAdmsRequestConstructor$.executeAndMonitorCopyActivity(SapOdpAdmsRequestConstructor.scala:206)
com.microsoft.dataflow.store.sapodp.SapOdpAdmsRequestConstructor$.com$microsoft$dataflow$store$sapodp$SapOdpAdmsRequestConstructor$$executeSapCDCCopyInternal(SapOdpAdmsReque*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was due to the additional privileges needed for the user to read data from SAP Operational Data Provisioning (ODP) framework. The full load works as there is not need to track the changes. To solve this issue, we added authorization objects S_DHCDCACT, S_DHCDCCDS, S_DHCDCSTP to the user profile which read data from SAP.